# CString array sort

Tags: c++, mfc

How can i sort (ascending or descending) an array of `CString`'s? I saw a lot of references to `std::vector`, but i can't find an example of converting a CString array to a vector.

Comment: Do you have an _array_ or `CString` (e.g. `CString myArray[10];`) or do you want to sort the characters _inside_ the `CString`?

Comment: an array of CStrings `CString myArray[10];`

Comment: You can use `std::sort()` on arrays also. See http://ideone.com/3o8B5r

Comment: [CString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688(v=vs.60).aspx) is a Microsoft MFC thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `CString` means ATL/MFC `CString`, complete demo program using **`std::sort`** to sort a raw array:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

#include <algorithm>        // std::sort
#include <iostream>         // std::wcout, std::endl
#include <utility>          // std::begin, std::end

std::wostream& operator<<( std::wostream& stream, CString const& s )
{
    return (stream << s.GetString());
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    CString strings[] = { "Charlie", "Alfa", "Beta" };

    sort( begin( strings ), end( strings ) );
    for( auto&& s : strings )
    {
        wcout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Using a `std::vector` instead of a raw array is a little bit more intricate, since Visual C++’s standard library implementation does not yet support `std::initialiser_list` per version 11.0. In the example below I use a raw array *to provide the data* (this is an example of converting a `CString` array to a `std::vector`, as you ask for). But the data could conceivably come from any source, e.g. reading the strings from a file:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

#include <algorithm>        // std::sort
#include <iostream>         // std::wcout, std::endl
#include <utility>          // std::begin, std::end
#include <vector>           // std::vector

std::wostream& operator<<( std::wostream& stream, CString const& s )
{
    return (stream << s.GetString());
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    char const* const stringData[] = { "Charlie", "Alfa", "Beta" };

    vector<CString> strings( begin( stringData ), end( stringData ) );

    sort( begin( strings ), end( strings ) );
    for( auto&& s : strings )
    {
        wcout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no difference in how the `std::vector` is *used*, compared to the raw array. At least at this level of abstraction. It's just more safe and with more rich functionality, compared to the raw array.

Answer (score 4):

Since the `CString` class have an `operator<` you should be able to use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
CString myArray[10];

// Populate array

std::sort(myArray, myArray + 10);
```

Comment: and in what order will `std::sort`?

Comment: @MRM In the order defined by `operator <` (from smallest to largest).

Comment: ok. And if i have a `CList<CString, CString&>`, how could i make a sort on it?

Comment: Copy it to a vector, sort the vector and copy it back, alternatively write your own sorting routine.

Comment: @john this is the exact kind of answer i find all over the internet :) i want to know how to do the copy.

Comment: @MRM Manually loop over the `CList` (or whatever MFC/ATL container you have) and insert into the standard container, sort the standard container, clear the MFC/ATL container, and loop over the standard container inserting the items into the MFC/ATL container.

Comment: @MRM It's just a for loop (or while loop). A bit too long to show you exactly how in a comment, but surely you can figure it out? You must have written loops through a CList before. If not then post the code you've attempted and I'm sure someone will fix it.

Comment: @john, yes i know how to perform a loop on a container and i've did it before, the actual "put" in a `vector` is a mistery for me. But @Cheers and hth. - Alf posted an answer and made me understand a bit the mechanism. Thanks!

Comment: @MRM push_back adds a string to the end of the vector, `vec.push_back(str);` This information is available in the internet, e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort a CList, you can take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1288/General-Purpose-Collection-Sorter).